# Update Flatlist when state array change on Functional component

Tags: react-native, socket.io

I have this code below, when the socket event is activated it is supposed to update the list (which is not happening), I've searched everywhere but I couldn't find how to make this list update, can anyone help me?

```
const [globalMessages, setGlobalMessages] = useState([]);
const chatList = useRef(null);

useEffect(()=>{
  socket.on("GlobalMessage", (globalMessageData) => {
     console.log(globalMessages.length)
     globalMessages.push(globalMessageData)
     setGlobalMessages(globalMessages)
  });
},[])

<FlatList 
  ref={chatList}
  onContentSizeChange={() => chatList.current.scrollToEnd() }
  onLayout={() => chatList.current.scrollToEnd() }
  data={globalMessages}
  extraData={globalMessages}
  keyExtractor={message => message._id}
  renderItem={(message) =>  {
     return (
        <ChatBubble 
           text={message.item.text}
           from={message.item.user.name}
           datetime= {message.item.createdAt}
           myId={playerData.id}
           msgfromId={message.item.user._id}
           containerStyle={styles.msgContainer}
           smallTextColor= "#6B6B6B"
           msgTextColor= "white"
        />
     )
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed this inside socket.on

```
setGlobalMessages([])   
setGlobalMessages(globalMessages)
```

and it worked as it should